# Nerdtree Tab witdth - how do I change the size?

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree

When I press `t` in nerdtree, it opens the file in a new tab. But the tabs are very small.

How do I make them longer (span the page)?

Comment: Are you sure it's a new tab? A tabpage in vim always covers the entire available screen area. Perhaps you are looking for how to resize _windows_? (`:help window-resize`)

Comment: Or do you mean the `tabline`?

Comment: Yes, tabline is what I was looking for. Apologies, I'm still very new to all these settings. How do I edit the width of the tabline

Comment: See `:help 'tabline'`, which links to information on how to set it to whatever you want